# Modern Ubuntu home media, security, and automation center

Tags: server, software-recommendation, security, multimedia, automation

I'm looking to set up a large computer to act as a home media center, a security system, and possibly home automation.

I'd like the following features

- 64 bit support
- Modern (based on a recent edition of Ubuntu)
- support for playing media from suppliers like (Amazon Prime, Hulu, Netflix)
- Thin client support (be able to have clients on TVs then transmit from the server to them)
- Motion sensitive security cameras
- Remote access (able to access the computer and cameras from where ever)

What solutions or even pre made distros are there for this?

if no Ubuntu solutions exist for this perhaps another distro might work as well.

Note: LinuxMCE fits most of this but it is out of date for which version of Ubuntu it works on and it does not support 64 bit.

Note: For the system I'm planing to use this computer https://system76.com/desktops/model/wilp11

Thank you

Comment: bbbbbbbbnnnnn1Your question is likely to be closed as too broad. First, ubuntu has supported 64 bit for years. Second, as far as "modern" use any supported version of ubuntu you wish. As far as making a security system, you need to google search. I priced it out recently and it is often cheaper to just purchase a dedicated security system and not all the features you want are available. See zoneminder http://www.zoneminder.com/

Comment: it did not seem so broad to me, as I saw a few like Myth TV that were very close but did not have the security side of things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably won't find one single distro with all those specific features, but you can probably install them if they can be found in the/a repository.

- I don't know if Myth TV can be integrated with Netflix, but
  [Plex](https://plex.tv/) might, although it's not free.
- Remote access to the server can be achieved with SSH (a secured connection)
  which is worth learning to use.

You will have to research the features/software packages, since most people won't have a all-in-one solution handy for you. Most things should be possible on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS 64-bit from what I've seen.